# Django unittests: The model is already registered Error

Tags: django, unit-testing

I come across several problems while trying django unittests library. Something strange happens:

I defined the test like this:

```
from django.core import management
from django.test import TestCase
from django.test.client import Client
from django.core import mail
from django.test.utils import setup_test_environment
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import connection
from goserver.models import ActiveList

class GoserverTestCase(TestCase):
    #fixtures = ['dat.json']

    def setUp(self):
        pass

    def test_active_list_works(self):
        c = Client()
        response = c.post('/')
        #print response.status_code
        self.assertEquals(True, True)
```

But after the execution of the code it returns following error:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------  Unit Test Code Coverage Results
---------------------------------------------------------------------- Traceback (most recent call last):   File "manage.py", line 11, in <module>
    execute_manager(settings)   File "/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/Django-1.0.2_final-py2.5.egg/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 340, in execute_manager
    utility.execute()   File "/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/Django-1.0.2_final-py2.5.egg/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 295, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv) File "/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/Django-1.0.2_final-py2.5.egg/django/core/management/base.py", line 192, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)   File "/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/Django-1.0.2_final-py2.5.egg/django/core/management/base.py", line 219, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)   File "/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/Django-1.0.2_final-py2.5.egg/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 33, in handle
    failures = test_runner(test_labels, verbosity=verbosity, interactive=interactive)   File "/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django_test_coverage-0.1-py2.5.egg/django-test-coverage/runner.py", line 58, in run_tests
    modules.extend(_package_modules(*pkg)) File "/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django_test_coverage-0.1-py2.5.egg/django-test-coverage/runner.py", line 92, in _package_modules
    modules.append(__import__(impstr + '.' + name, {}, {}, ['']))   File "/Users/oleg/jin/goclub/trunk/jin/goserver/admin.py", line 11, in <module>
    admin.site.register(ActiveList, ActiveListAdmin)   File "/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/Django-1.0.2_final-py2.5.egg/django/contrib/admin/sites.py", line 64, in register
    raise AlreadyRegistered('The model %s is already registered' % model.__name__) django.contrib.admin.sites.AlreadyRegistered: The model ActiveList is already registered silver:jin oleg$
```

Admin file looks like this:

```
from goserver.models import ActiveList, Game
from django.contrib import admin

class ActiveListAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('user', "is_Bot", "isActive")

admin.site.register(ActiveList, ActiveListAdmin)
admin.site.register(Game)
```

I run it all this way:
python manage.py test goserver

Also noticed that if I remove lines 
            c = Client()
            response = c.post('/')

from a test case definition, then no error appears

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the traceback, it looks like you have an app called `django_test_coverage-0.1` which is importing your app's `admin.py`.

It is probably importing it from a different location, such as `yourproject.yourapp.admin` as opposed to `yourapp.admin`. Since it's technically seen as a different module, it is re-imported and the `admin.site.register` calls are made again. This causes the `AlreadyRegistered` error.

My suggestion would be to remove `django_test_coverage` app (or fix it).

Comment: I have a similar problem. I was using django-nose with the option --cover-inclusive that includes all python files under working directory in coverage report.

Comment: @ArthurAlvim Have you managed to solve this while also running nose with the --cover-inclusive option?

Comment: @goldstein I gave up trying to use the django-nose + coverage. Instead , I'm using django-coverage separately. Give a check in https://bitbucket.org/kmike/django-coverage or the github mirror https://github.com/kmike/django-coverage.

Answer (score 0):

My questions,

- I don't see what is base type/class for TestCase - is it Django Test one, or from Unittest?
  it is better to use from Django
- How are you runnig test? using Django internal test command, by nose, by unittest? By Traceback I thing test command, but I am not quite sure.
- What is you definitions for ActiveAdminList and ActiveList? Have you got maybe class Admin in Meta?

Comment: Thanks for answer! I added needed info to original description

Comment: Can you paste content of the ActiveList model?, I think that there could be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I solve this commenting the admin.autodiscover() line in the proye